# SVN Not a working directory

Tags: svn, magento, locking

So guys I tried a commit on our server and end up in this stupid loop

```
www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn ci -m 'Rewrite rules added'
svn: Working copy '/www/sites/www.domain.com/files/html' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

So I go ahead and try a cleanup, but end up with the error.....

```
www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn cleanup
svn: 'var/session' is not a working copy directory
```

Okay, so var shouldn't be used anyway so lets try to ignore var/

```
www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn rm var --keep-local
svn: Working copy '.' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

And it asks me to cleanup again... I'm in a viscious circle here, anyone know
what to do?

**UPDATE**

As per another thread I tried moving it

```
$ mv var var_
$ svn cleanup
$ svn revert var
Failed to revert 'var' -- try updating instead.
$ mv var_/ var
$ svn add var
www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn add var
svn: Working copy 'var' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
```

And also

```
$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html/var$ mv session session_
$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html/var$ cd ../
$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn cleanup
$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn ci -m 'Rewrite Rules'
    svn: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: Directory '/www/sites/www.domain.com/files/html/var/session' is missing
    svn: Directory '/www/sites/www.domain.com/files/html/var/session' is missing

$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ mv var/session_ var/session
$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn ci -m 'Rewrite Rules'
    svn: Working copy '/www/sites/www.domain.com/files/html' locked
    svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)

$ www.domain.com@www01:~/html$ svn cleanup
    svn: 'var/session' is not a working copy directory
```

But no dice....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give concrete advice without knowing the specifics of your file and project structure **but** subversion is telling you the `var/session` folder isn't a part of your project — it seems like `svn cleanup` assumes all folders found are a part of your (or a) project.

You'll either need to temporarily move `var/session` out of your project directory, and then restore it after the cleanup **or** just blow the `var/session` folder away (assuming this is a development/staging server, and your session information isn't critical).

Comment: I tried that and am now getting the error **svn: Directory '/www/sites/www.domain.com/files/html/var/session/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing**

Comment: Try re-checking out and/or restoring JUST the session folder from your project after renaming

Comment: Yep that worked great, thanks Alan, BTW I thought your name looked familiar. I Bought your book on no frills magento about 7 months back. Excellent stuff man!